# Can I install web2py (or similar frameworks) on my hosting server? (I have only ftp access)

Tags: installation, web2py

My domain is hosted on a linux-server (by 1und1.de). I do not have ssh access to my server, I have only ftp.

They provide abundant PHP support. Through their web interface, I can install wordpress, get admin pages, and can have blogs (for eg.).

There is basic support for python (my hello.py works). But I don't see any option to install any of the python-frameworks.. unlike wordpress.

Would it be possible to install web2py, django, or any other framework for my domain? 
Would it suffice to unzip web2py's source into a folder in the server?

Thanks,
TMM.

Answer (score 4):

Installing web2py via FTP is not a problem. You just unzip on your local machine and then FTP it to the server. There is no installation process in web2py. The problem is starting it. I doubt they will allow you to start the built-in web2py server (rocket). Somehow you will have to connect web2py to the web server they provide. How depends on what they provide. Let's assume they have Apache. Ask them if they have mod_wsgi and if they have instructions to connect any python app to apache using wsgi. You may want to seek help on the web2py mailing list.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I shall contact them and see what can be done.